# getimagesize causing php error in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6, getimagesize

So I'm trying to use getimagesize() to work out the aspect ratio of some images and size them accordingly, but it's producing an error in magento.  Here is my code:

```
<? $brand_image_url = $mediaURL . 'catalog/category/' . $_subcategory->load($id)->getBrandLogo();
$brand_image_size = getimagesize($brand_image_url);
$brand_image_ratio = $brand_image_size[0]/$brand_image_size[1];

if($brand_image_ratio<100/48){ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $mediaURL; ?>catalog/category/<?php echo $_subcategory->load($id)->getBrandLogo(); ?>" alt="" height="48" /></span>
<?php }
else {
?><img src="<?php echo $mediaURL; ?>catalog/category/<?php echo $_subcategory->load($id)->getBrandLogo(); ?>" alt="" width="100" /></span> <?php
}?>
```

And here is the error it is producing:

```
Warning: getimagesize(http://dev.urbanrider.co.uk/media/catalog/category/agv-logo.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
in /home/uriderdev/web/app/design/frontend/urbanrider/default/template/wee_fpc/catalog/navigation/top.phtml on line 119

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'getimagesize(ht...', '/home/uriderdev...', 119, Array)
#1 /home/uriderdev/web/app/design/frontend/urbanrider/default/template/wee_fpc/catalog/navigation/top.phtml(119): getimagesize('http://dev.urba...')
#2 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/uriderdev...')
#3 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/urbanr...')
#4 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
#10 /home/uriderdev/web/app/design/frontend/urbanrider/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(81): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
#11 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/uriderdev...')
#12 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/urbanr...')
#13 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#17 /home/uriderdev/web/app/design/frontend/urbanrider/default/template/page/1column.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#18 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/uriderdev...')
#19 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/urbanr...')
#20 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Urbanrider_CustomCms_IndexController), 'home')
#26 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Urbanrider_CustomCms_IndexController), 'home')
#27 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#28 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#29 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /home/uriderdev/web/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /home/uriderdev/web/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a HTTP 403 (forbidden). 
You don't have permission to access /media/catalog/category/agv-logo.jpg on this server.

In other words, you could not get the image data from the provided URL.

Comment: ah!  what permissions does the file need to have? it's set to 644 currently

Comment: 644 should be OK, maybe the folder is not?

Comment: This also could be a disguised 404.. is the path to the file correct?

Comment: Replacing http:// **dev** .urbanrider.co.uk/media/catalog/category/agv-logo.jpg with **www** works for me.

Comment: could it be that the dev site is whitelisted? surely because it's the server that shouldn't matter though?  I can't really change that code as it needs to automatically produce the URL based on the site

Comment: I have added a work around replacing 'dev' with 'www' whenever it's present in that bit of code and that seems to work, not perfect but it'll do!